# Higher train set accuracy, Lower test set accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Im using CNN to classify wireless signal.
Meamwhile I meet some strange problem - when trainset accuray is 80%, I got 79% testset accuracy, but when trianset accuracy is 93%, the testset accuray fall to 71%. Anyone have same problem before?

My net is based on `keras` + `tensorflow`.
the detail of net is :

```
CNN(512,(2,2),tanh)   
Batch_normaliztion  
flatten()   
DNN(512,elu)   
DNN(256,elu)  
DNN(128,softmax)

opt=adam
loss = mse
```

THANKS

Comment: For very high trainset accuracy, your model may be overfitting the dataset(not sure as you did'nt mentioned about your dataset).

Comment: Thanks,the dataset is collect by myself,consist of some wireless sgnals like WIFI,zigbee,LoRa,RFID etc.
you mean the overfitting may happen even trainset accuracy is just 90%?

Comment: yes, it is because your test accuracy is very low (try to use dropout layers). Other reason maybe that during splitting, your test dataset contains completely different values compares to train dataset (e.g. test set contains information of wifi, etc from a region which train set doesn't contains, or any similar issues)

Comment: This is probably a case of high variance problem (over-fitting). Are you sure the Training data and Testing data come from the same source? (for example location) If they are not, split them evenly according to their source. You could also try adding some regularization techniques like DropOut.

Comment: Thanks,Trainning data and Testing data are from same source.(in same location and enviroment).I think its overfitting.and Im going to increase Dropout.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a case of over fitting.How did you get the training accuracy to go from 80% to 93%? Was it just by running more epochs?.
If over fitting is what is happening add dropout layers to the model. This should improve the validation accuracy but it may take more epochs to achieve the desired training accuracy. Another alternative is to use regularizers in the dense layers.
The more complex your model is the more it is prone to over fitting so you might try running the model with just two dense layers or alternatively reduce the number of nodes in the hidden layers.

Comment: Yes,I improve the accuracy by adding more epochs.I follow your suggestions,Its helpful.the accuracy of testing set is better.Thanks a lot.